# TeamCity Run build configuration from a different build configuration

Tags: teamcity

I'm using team City.
I have a build configuration that actually deploys my build artifacts on a remote machine (for the sake of this question I'll call it the "Deployment" build configuration). this works great.
I want to run the "Deployment" configuration in a loop that deploy the binaries on different machines (each iteration of the loop, deploys the binaries on a single machine). is there a way to achieve this with Team City?

thanks

Comment: Is your build runner MSBuild? If so you can do this from within a MSBuild file.

Comment: I have several build runners, not just MS build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a configuration loop, but you could extract a template for your deployment configuration and then add configurations based on that template for each machine you want to deploy to. You'd just want a build parameter in the template to hold the path or connection details for each target machine.

Comment: I did use template but since I have many machines, I need something more centralized. In order to achieve my goal I used a single build configuration that is being activated from a REST script I built. The REST script sets the parameters per machine.